# Prove limit of sequence at infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Prove: Let $f:R→R$ monotonically increasing, show that the sequences $f(n)$, $f(\frac{1}{n})$ limit exists at infinity.

I'm totally understand the claim but don't know how to write it right.

Answer (score 0):

The sequences  $a_n =f(n) $ and $b_n =f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ are monotone, but every monotone sequence of real numbers has a limit finite or not.